# Game score with python

Tags: python, pygame, global-variables, loss, thonny

I need help making a score board for each round of my Tic Tac Toe game, I would like it so whenever a round ends it updates cscore (computer score)or pscore (player score) by 1.

Any feedback on my code would be greatly appreciated since I am fairly new to python.

I have put the score related code I already have below

```py
import random
def main():
    global cscore
    cscore = 0
    global pscore
    pscore = 0
```

```
if turn == 'player':
    drawBoard(theBoard)
    move = getPlayerMove(theBoard)
    makeMove(theBoard, playerLetter, move)
    if isWinner(theBoard, playerLetter):
        drawBoard(theBoard)
        print('Hooray! You have won the game!')
        pscore += 1
        print(main)
                
        gameIsPlaying = False
    else:
        if isBoardFull(theBoard):
            drawBoard(theBoard)
            print('The game is a tie!')
            print(main)
                

            break
        else:
            turn = 'computer'
else:
    move = getComputerMove(theBoard, computerLetter)
    makeMove(theBoard, computerLetter, move)
    if isWinner(theBoard, computerLetter):
        drawBoard(theBoard)
        print('The computer has beaten you! You lose.')
        cscore += 1
        print(main)
              
        gameIsPlaying = False
    else:
        if isBoardFull(theBoard):
            drawBoard(theBoard)
            print('The game is a tie!')
            print(main)
                   

            break
        else:
            turn = 'player'
if not playAgain():
break

main()
```

Comment: please fix the indentation also what happened when you tried to make the score board?

Comment: Also, those `print(main)` lines will output something like `function main at 0x.....`. What did you want to do there? Note that if you _called_ the function instead or _referencing_ it the result would be even worse: it would output `None` but you would reset the scores to 0!

Answer (score -1):

at the start of the function with the loop of the game, that loop that doesn't stop, you need to add

```
global cscore, pscore
```

Just like in the `main()` function. If you didn't - this is way it doesn't updating to you.

By the way, better way will be to create a `class` for a player (I am aware that you are new to python so this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDa-Z5JzLYM might help you), the class would look a bit like that:

```
class Player():

    def __init__(self, is_human):
        self.score = 0
        self.is_human = is_human
```